# How can I access to a text box which is in a group box?

Tags: c#, winforms, hierarchical

I designed a windows form which has `textbox1` placed on the Form directly and `textbox2` on the `goupbox1`. Running below code only changes text of `textbox1`. I googled a lot but I could not find the solution. How can i reach `textbox2`?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (TextBox txtBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        txtBox.Enter += textBox_Enter;
        txtBox.Text = "123"; //To test if the text box is recognized or not
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion.
I'd recommend you to use the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllControls<T>(Control control)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.OfType<T>();
    return control.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Aggregate(controls, (current, c) => current.Concat(GetAllControls<T>(c)));
}
```

Usage:

```
var textBoxes = GetAllControls<TextBox>(this);
```

Comment: Dear Dmitry, your answer was exactly what I needed. But there is no enough explanation for it. Is it possible for you to explain more about your solution?

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Please ask a specific question,

Comment: Can you please provide me some keywords to google your solution way?